# Boot Error - Hiren Boot CD 15.2

Tags: boot, bios, boot-cd

I have Gigabyte 880GM Motherboard that supports Hybrid EFI technology. It has a thin layer of EFI on top of BIOS to enable booting off GPT partition in EFI mode.
Earlier I had Windows XP on it in NON-EFI Mode. I have a Hiren Boot CD 15.2 that booted flawlessly then when it was XP.

Now I have Windows 7 64 in EFI Mode with GPT Partition scheme. Now when I try to boot using same CD I get the error

‘**No PXE Stack commands (hangup means you have a problematic config**’ and nothing further happens. The HDD LED just glows continuously and it never boots.

I thought it might be due to EFI config so I disabled EFI in BIOS and disconnected the HDD from the system. Now it’s just a basic hardware without HDD and NON-EFI boot mode. Still I get the same error.

I wonder where things are going wrong and what could be the next troubleshooting step. The CD is bootable. I crosschecked that by booting my Sony Vaio Windows 7 laptop thru it. The message still appears for a very short moment on laptop but it does not hang there and successfully boots to Hiren Boot CD Menu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hiren's does not run on UEFI hardware, its kenel was not compiled with the required UEFI parameters
2. Your error tells me there's something wrong with your firmware. Please confirm you have correctly established the right boot order, and that effectively you are booting in Legacy mode if you really want to boot Hiren's.